# nuget pack content files only

Tags: package, nuget

I'd like to create a nuget package (from some c# project), but I don't want to embed the generated dll, but just some static files instead.

I added a  tag at the end of my nuspec file, but nuget pack command continues to embed the project.dll in the package. 
The thing is I don't want this dll to be published.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks,

Régis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can create a *.nuspec* file that simply references the content files.

You must use `nuget pack MyPackage.nuspec`

Don't pack the *.csproj* file as that causes NuGet to include the built assembly.

See http://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec reference for more info.

Comment: Hmm. Apparently my answer helped the person asking the question. What do you suggest would make a better answer?

Comment: A sample nuspec file would make it better, imo ^_^

Answer (score 5):

To package a file as content, you must use `target=content` when listing the file in your .nuspec document.

To create a 'content only' nuget package, you must use a `<files>` node to list the files.

A `<files>` node must be a sibling of the `<metadata>` node.

A `<file>` node must be a child of a `<files>` node.

To include a file as content, set the *target* attribute in a `<file>` node to 'content'.

Example:

```
  <files>
    <file src="{filePath}" target="content"/>
  </files>
```

As previously mentioned, you must then pack the .nuspec file rather than a .csproj file:

```
nuget pack *.nuspec
```

I found the `target=content` trick here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files

Answer (score 3):

For contentFiles i use this way in the nuspec file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>    
    <id>DummyNuget</id>
    <version>1.0.1-alpha</version>
    <title>DummyNuget</title>
    <authors>DummyNuget</authors>
    <owners>DummyNuget</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>DummyNuget</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>2019</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <contentFiles>
        <files include="**\*.*" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="<path to files>\*.*" target="contentFiles\any\any" />    
  </files>
</package>
```

files to put the local files in the nuget package then contentFiles in the metadata to put all the files in the project as content copy to output